# Digraphs: Is this an example of a digraph with no cycles, but a closed walk?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to apply this vocabulary: cycle and closed walk on a digraph.

So since a cycle is a walk such that all the vertices are different except the last two, and a closed walk is just a walk that starts and ends with the same vertex, is this a good example of a digraph with no cycles but with a closed walk?

1 -> 1 -> 1

It can't be a cycle because all three vertices are the same, and it starts and ends with 1, so does this count?

It's confusing to me because when I see the words "same vertex" I'm not sure if it means the same vertex value or the literal same instance of the vertex.

Thanks.

Comment: That's called a loop.

Comment: A cycle is a path such that the start vertex and end vertex are the same. The choice of the start vertex in a cycle is arbitrary.

Comment: So am I correct to say that this loop is not a cycle?

Comment: In graph theory, a loop (also called a self-loop or a "buckle") is an edge that connects a vertex to itself. In graph theory, a path in a graph is a sequence of edges which connect a sequence of vertices. A cycle is a path such that the start vertex and end vertex are the same. The choice of the start vertex in a cycle is arbitrary. Can you complete?